# Calling a C function from Lua

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to call a function from a C project but I don´t know how to do it.

Here is my code ("treatments.c"):

```
#include <string.h>
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

static int treatments_load_image (lua_State * L) {
    lua_pushnumber(L,10);
    return 1;   
}

static const luaL_Reg RegisterFunctions[] =
{
    { "treatments", treatments_load_image },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

int luaopen_treatments(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_newtable(L);

    #if LUA_VERSION_NUM < 502
        luaL_register(L, NULL, LuaExportFunctions);
    #else
        luaL_setfuncs(L, LuaExportFunctions, 0);
    #endif

    return 1;
}
```

In my .lua file, I´m trying to do something like this:

```
local treatments = require 'treatments'
```

And I get the error below:

```
lua: run.lua:15: module 'treatments' not found:
no field package.preload['treatments']
no file './treatments.lua'
...
```

The ".c" file is in the same folder than ".lua" file. I'm not using any MAKEFILE file.

If it helps, I'm using Lua 5.1 =)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

> The ".c" file is in the same folder than ".lua" file. I'm not using
>   any MAKEFILE file

No, you must build your `c` source file into shared library (dll for windows, or so for linux), then put that shared library in lua `package.cpath`, see http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial

Comment: Thanks @secmask =) I read that I must have a ".so" file.. so I after the following code: "gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o treatments.so  -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -llua5.1   treatments.c" I created one. And I'm getting this error when running application: "lua: attempt to index a string value
stack traceback:
 [C]: ?
 [C]: in function 'require'
 run.lua:15: in main chunk
 [C]: ?
"

Comment: The line 15 is "local treatments = require 'treatments'" ..do you know what´s going on?

Comment: It works if I use "require 'treatments'" instead of "local treatments = require 'treatments'" oO

Comment: Is that array called "RegisterFunctions" actually. Actually now it´s working with the ".so" file =) that was the problem! And thank you very much @secmask

Answer (score 2):

Lua's `require` deals with files containing Lua code **or shared libraries** in the case of C. You need to compile the C source code into a shared library and then load that, which should "return" a table (i.e. push it onto the stack), as usual.

Comment: Yes, or a .dll under Windows ;)